# Jackson annotations being ignored in Spring

Tags: spring, jackson

I'm trying to make a property in a domain class hidden but it keeps appearing in the outputted JSON. I'm using Jackson 2.0 and Spring 3.1.1

Output of /users/1:

```
{"id":1,"password":null,"email":"someone@somewhere.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}
```

My domain class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private String mPassword;
    ... 
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        mPassword = password;
    }
    ...
}
```

My springmvc config:

```
...
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private UserService mUserService;

    public UserController(){}

    @Inject
    public void setUserController(UserService userService){
        mUserService=userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(mUserService.getUser(id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that Spring doesn't work with Jackson 2.0. This has been solved in the following way:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
          class="own.implementation.of.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc
             .annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="requireSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

And the own.implementation.of.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is based on this:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java?format=ok

But use ObjectMapper and other Jackson classes from Jackson 2.0 instead of Jackson 1.*

Comment: I think I'll just downgrade to Jackson 1.9 which seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Unless you need features from 2.0 (like passing objects with bi-directional relationships). That's why I upgraded to 2.0.

Answer (score 11):

Support for Jackson 2 has been added to Spring 3.1.2 (backported from Spring 3.2 - [SPR-9507](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9507)). Just upgrade your project from Spring 3.1.1 to Spring 3.1.2, and Jackson 2 works with the configuration you already have.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to upgrading to `Spring 3.1.2`, you also have to change the message converter to  `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson**2**HttpMessageConverter`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Spring 4 version, You will have to do following, Update dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace older codehaus annotation  import to following, if do not do this, your older annotation like JsonIgnoreProperties will not work with new version of Jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
```

Remove mediaTypes from below, it has been deprecated.

> ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

, Not needed, will be picked up from activation framework jar, Jackson view should be using

> MappingJackson2JsonView

```
<beans:property name="viewResolvers">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="order" value="0"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="defaultViews">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

Answer (score 0):

My configuration looks like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:order="1">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
   </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <!-- this is not important for your jackson problem -->
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" p:order="2" depends-on="tilesConfigurer"/>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

My controller looks like this

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
   public SearchResponse search(@RequestParam(value = QUERY, required = true) String query) {
       return generateSearchResponse(query);
   }
}
```

My SearchResponse is more complex structure but it contains this type of objects.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "popis" })
public class Kurz implements Serializable {
    private String nazev;
    private String popis;
}
```

Comment: Adding the property didn't seem to make any difference, it's probably not required.

Comment: Try put ignore annotation on the field not getter. I think Jackson by default read and set directly form field.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I don't think it's using Jackson - it's able to serialise the JSON without the Jackson jar being available. Also I shouldn't use @ResponseBody with ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, instead I should return the view "json" or use HttpMessageConverter instead.