# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException with Spring 3.1.2 and Jackson 1.9.11

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

**~R**

I'm trying to do Spring MVC REST JSON channel with automatic conversion to JSON using Jackson. Although I'm doing everything as recommended in other StackOverflow questions, I'm getting `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` and my beans/lists are not converted to JSON. I'm running the code on **Jetty**.

I've followed the instruction from [UTF-8 encoding problem in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc), [Spring 3.0 making JSON response using jackson message converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259551/spring-3-0-making-json-response-using-jackson-message-converter) and [Jackson annotations being ignored in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085088/jackson-annotations-being-ignored-in-spring/11495679#11495679), but none of them enables me to send neither bean nor a `List<String>`. Both return HTTP status 406. Only the method returning String succeeds with HTTP 200.

My method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", produces = "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getList() {
    return createList();
}
```

Spring file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.myapp.rest" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Adding this section also doesn't help:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:order="1">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
   </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The request HTTP header is generated by jQuery and looks like that:

> Accept    application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language   de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>   User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/18.0

However, I get HTTP 406 with HTML error message, and the following lines in log file:

> Resolving exception from handler [public de.myapp.rest.TestBean
>   de.myapp.rest.Test.getList()]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation

So the question is, what I'm missing here? Why the jackson converter is not registered/how can I debug it? I'm running the code via `jetty:run`. But it **should not** matter, since Spring is application-server-independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@RequestMapping` you have `produces = "text/plain"`, but your request header says `Accept application/json, text/javascript`. There is no match.

Use either `produces="application/json"` or don't use `produces` at all. It's main use case is to provide more than one method for the same URL, each producing output in a different format (JSP, JSON, XML ...).

Comment: Yes, yesterday I had procuces application/json but then I was changing it for tests. Today I've applied the solutions from stackoverflow, but I've forgotten to change the produces.