# Java JsonIgnore is not hiding field

Tags: java, json

Need to hide one field from Json, but leave it, because need to use it in another method ( `get` ). Tried to do it, but `id` field is still visible in Json. Whats wrong here?

Dependencies:

```
<properties>
  <!-- Use the latest version whenever possible. -->
  <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.53</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/jaxrs-ri -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Trying to do it this way:
package test.model;

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import test.model.DbTest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "id" })
public final class Home {
    @JsonIgnore
    private final BigDecimal id;

    private final String date;

    public Home( //
            BigDecimal id, //
            String date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public final BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public static final Home newInstance( 
            DbTest test) {
        return new Home( 
                test.getId(), 
                test.getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting @JsonIgnore on the getter?

Comment: I tried to add this before `getId` and it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or remove 'final' from field

Comment: Tried to add this in pom.xml and removed `final`, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Deividas.r I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894955/spring-jsonignore-not-working, hope it works