# Why is my email getting cut off with Spring MVC and REST?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Can someone please tell me why my email address is getting cut.. for testing we use email address like **test@aol.com.dev**

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profilenumber/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getProfileNumber(@PathVariable String email, ModelMap model) throws ResourceNotFoundException
{
    logger.debug("Looking for Profile Number for: " + email);
}
```

The output of my logger.debug is **test@aol.com** we are losing the **.dev** which we need.  Can someone please tell me why we would be losing it

Java have this in my WebConfig but it does not help

```
@Bean
    public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping ()
    {
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping b = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();

        b.setUseDefaultSuffixPattern(false);
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it but change the code to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profilenumber/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getProfileNumber(@PathVariable String email, ModelMap model) throws ResourceNotFoundException
{
    logger.debug("Looking for Profile Number for: " + email);
}
```

It looks like thats all I had to do

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring 3.0.x add the following to your spring config file:

```
<!-- Spring Configuration needed to avoid URI using dots to be truncated -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

if you are using a more recent version of spring check this discussion: [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Spring default configuration cuts off extensions in urls.

Comment: how do I do this with javaconig?? I dont use xml files

Comment: not sure about the java way of configuring it. I am still using 3.0.5 where most of the configuration is done via xml.