# SpringMVC: Inconsistent mapping behavior depending on url extension

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4

I have a RESTful spring based endpoint to get assets stored in a db to a javascript editor. The relevant parts boil down to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ThemeEndpoint.ENDPOINT_NAME)
public class ThemeEndpoint {

public static final String ENDPOINT_NAME = "/themes"; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}/css/{assetName:.*}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Asset getCssItem(
        @PathVariable("id") ThemeId id, 
        @PathVariable("assetName") String name) {
    CssThemeAsset themeAsset = themeService.getCssAsset(
                id, ThemeAssetId.fromString(name));
    Asset asset = new Asset();
    asset.name = themeAsset.getName();
    asset.text = themeAsset.getContent();
    return asset;
}
```

This works as expected for urls like

```
http://localhost:8080/app-url/rest/themes/ac18a080-a2f1-11e3-84f4-600308a0bd14/css/main.less
```

but fails as soon as i change the extension to `.css`.

After some debugging i'm quite sure the request is not even mapped if i use an url like

```
http://localhost:8080/app-url/rest/themes/ac18a080-a2f1-11e3-84f4-600308a0bd14/css/main.css
```

With a high log level i can see that the mapping is catched by spring:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
    - Mapped "{[/themes/{id}/css/{assetName:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],
                consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" 
      onto public xxx.endpoint.ThemeEndpoint$Asset
          xxx.endpoint.ThemeEndpoint.getCssItem(
              net.lacho.svc.themes.api.ThemeId,java.lang.String)
```

and with a non .css extension the controller is called:

```
Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/themes/ac18a080-a2f1-11e3-84f4-600308a0bd14/css/main.less]
  : [{[/themes/{id}/css/{assetName:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],
        consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}]
```

but as soon as i use .css as extension - bang:

```
Looking up handler method for path /themes/ac18a080-a2f1-11e3-84f4-600308a0bd14/css/test.css
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - 
    Resolving exception from handler [null]:  
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: 
    Could not find acceptable representation
```

`web.xml`and MVC-Config as requested:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="false">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
package net.lacho.opcenter.bootstrap;


public class WebApplicationBootstrapper implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocation(ApplicationConfig.class.getName());

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        registerRestDispatcher(container);
        registerDefaultDispatcher(container);

        container.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", UTF8EncodingFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/*");
        container.addFilter("headSupportFilter", HeadSupportFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/*");

        DelegatingFilterProxy shallowFrontendContextFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy("shallowFrontendContextProviderLocalFilter");
        shallowFrontendContextFilterProxy.setTargetFilterLifecycle(true);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic shallowFrontendFilter = container.addFilter("ShallowFrontendContextFilter", shallowFrontendContextFilterProxy);
        shallowFrontendFilter.setInitParameter("ignoreNullClient", "true");
        shallowFrontendFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/*");

        container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/*");

        container.addFilter("FrontendContextFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("frontendContextProviderLocalFilter"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/*");

        container.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,  true,  "/rest/*");;
    }

    public void registerRestDispatcher(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restDispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        restDispatcherContext.register(RestCommonsMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic restDispatcher = container.addServlet("rest-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(restDispatcherContext));
        restDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        restDispatcher.addMapping("/rest/*");
    }

    public void registerDefaultDispatcher(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("backend-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*", "/index");
    }

}
```

MVC-config:

```
package net.lacho.opcenter.bootstrap;



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.lacho.opcenter.ui"} )
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ... many lines removed, containing interceptors and velocity-config ...

@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/_r/_s/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static-resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(365 * 86400);
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/_r/_d/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static-uncached-resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: What does your web.xml and mvc mapping config look like? guessing there is something that recognises *.css as a resource and maps it to the resource servlet

Comment: How do you convert `Assert` to HTTP response? Show your custom `HttpMessageConverter`, if you use it.

Comment: @rhinds added requested files.

Comment: @axtavt No custom converter. I import Jackson 2 via maven and it's picked up by spring (as i said, the controller gets called and the marshalling to JSON works as long as my url doesn't end in .css).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature...

As @axtavt and @rhinds have supposed, something is messing around which the content type. The browsers sends a correct `Accept: application/json` but spring ignores this and uses the extension of the url (aarrgh). From the docs:

> 16.16.4 Configuring Content Negotiation
>
> ```
> You can configure how Spring MVC determines the requested media types from the client for
> request mapping as well as for content negotiation purposes. The available options are to 
> check the file extension in the request URI, the "Accept" header, a request parameter, as 
> well as to fall back on a default content type. By default, file extension in the request 
> URI is checked first and the "Accept" header is checked next.
> ```

The solution is quite simple as you can disable this "feature":

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RestCommonsMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

}
```

See also [Spring does not ignore file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23578742/1686330) for xml-config.

#### Related

- [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16332092/1686330)

Answer (score 1):

I had required an extra step in my special case. I would like to add an extra information to @dirk-lachowski's great comment in case someone else needs. In my case I am importing an extension from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ SearchWebMvcConfigurationSupport.class })
public class SearchSpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

If you need to override `requestMappingHandlerMapping` method then you also have to add `m.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);`

```
@Configuration
public class SearchWebMvcConfigurationSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping m = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        m.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true); // This makes your endpoints receive full path, including servlet mapping (you probably will not need this)
        m.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return m;
    }
}
```