# Spring does not ignore file extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, uri, http-status-code-406

In my Spring XML I have the following snippet:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>        
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

From what I understand, this means that Spring should **NOT** register "abc.*" and "abc/" when I have a mapping for "abc".

In one of my controllers I have a method which writes an image to the response:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{path}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public void getPath(
        @PathVariable String path,
        HttpServletResponse res) {

    ...
}
```

This works great when I request something like "abc", but when I request "abc.com" it throws a 406 error with the text:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."
```

When I request "abc.img", the "path" parameter only receives the text "abc"; Spring omits the extension.

It seems Spring is not correctly ignoring the suffix pattern. Why is this?

**Edit**: *I translated the java config from Dirk's comment, and the following XML seems to fix this issue:*

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>        
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

*I'm still not sure why the original code I had was not working, but this has resolved my issue*

Comment: For the record, I've also tried using @RequestMapping(value="{path:.+}"), but with no luck

Comment: Maybe you have been hitten by the same problem than i. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22329393/1686330

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the same issue! I used the equivalent XML from that question and was able to fix my problem. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a request comes in to the spring dispatcher, part of the controller mapping/matching is matching accepted media types on the client side to producible media types on the controller side (so you can have controllers that are only distinguishable by their produced media types).

The bad news is that springmvc in its default configuration favors the **extension** of the requested url over any accept header in the request.

In your example, when you are requesting `abc` there is no match on the extension so other contentent negotiation strategies are kicking in eventually resolving to the right type (via `accept` header). But if you request `abc.com` spring will derive a mime type of `application/octet-stream` that doesn't match the `produces` of your controller and generating a `406` (because there is no matching controller).

You can find the default mime matching for path extensions in the spring-context-support.jar in `org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types` (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/resources/org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types#L278 ).

You can  disable this 'feature' in your dispatcher config so spring will not use the path extension to resolve the mime-type:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

If you are using java config have a look at my [related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22329393/1686330).

Comment: Perfect answer. But don't forget to specify the custom Content Negotiation Manager in the annotation driven -> ''<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />''

Comment: Also see: https://devpolito.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/ignore-file-extensions-in-spring-mvc/ for Java Config

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Or you use the [link in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22329393/1686330).

Comment: Starting from release 5.3, `favorPathExtension` defaults to false, therefore this workaround is no longer required. See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match).