# Spring Web Controller return XML under .html extension

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm writing a `Controller` to replace a legacy system which serves an xml document - but the url has a `.html` extension

My controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{name}.html",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody XmlContent getContent(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
    return service.getXmlContent();
}
```

When I try and hit the URL I get a 406 error:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

If I change the request mapping to be `.xml` it all works fine. Is there a component that I need to disable - something that's intercepting the `.html` part of the request and refusing to map it to xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar a similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578742/spring-does-not-ignore-file-extension) using spring xml configuration. For annotation based configuration you just need to add this configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```