# Path variables containing .com, .org are truncated in REST API

Tags: java, rest, path-variables

I am facing a strange issue.
This is my REST API mapping

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = { "/{email}" },
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    params = "time")
public void getEmail(
    @PathVariable("email") final String sender,
    @RequestParam(value = "time", required = true) final long time)
```

When I call API like this

```
/someone@someone.com?time=10
```

I observe that `sender` contains `someone@someone` instead of `someone@someone.com`.

When I give it like this

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = { "/{email:.+}" },
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    params = "time")
public void getEmail(
    @PathVariable("email") final String sender,
    @RequestParam(value = "time", required = true) final long time)
```

I get 406 error.

I tried this too.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Still no help.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/{email}` and `@PathVariable("sender")`? You're sure about the naming?

Comment: Hi, I updated with correct names

Comment: Need more context. What library are these annotations from?

Comment: These are Spring MVC annotations... btw. I've just verified the behaviour. Will check where the issue might be.

Comment: You will find a lot of explanations in this other post from SO [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from `RequestMapping` JavaDoc:

> @PathVariable annotated parameters (Servlet-only) for access to URI
>   template values (i.e. /hotels/{hotel}). Variable values will be
>   converted to the declared method argument type. **By default, the URI
>   template will match against the regular expression [^.]*** (i.e. any
>   character other than period), but this can be changed by specifying
>   another regular expression, like so: /hotels/{hotel:\d+}.
>   Additionally, @PathVariable can be used on a Map to
>   gain access to all URI template variables.

Your second mapping definition is correct and works. You haven't probably tested it correctly.

Comment: Hi When I give regular expression, it returns 406 error. I have updated the question

Comment: Error 406 is about `Accept` header. How are you testing your REST services? Also I can see that your handler method is `void`... not exactly sure how Spring is supposed to handle responses to such methods.

Comment: Hi, I am using firefox plugin RESTClient to test

Comment: And are you setting any explicit `Accept` header? Also I would say it is pretty uncommon to not return any value from handler method... (`void` is interpretted as `null`). There might be problem with finding correct HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler => hence error about unsupported response content type...