# Escaping url based parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

This is a curly one. But I've built an autosuggester component that uses a url based lookup in Spring MVC.

I've got a minor bug where I can't search by the email address because of some sort of HTTP Converter problem.

This doesn't work
`http://localhost:8080/admin/customers/json/customer_suggest/rich@mailinator.com`

This does work

`http://localhost:8080/admin/customers/json/customer_suggest/rich@mailinator.co`

It's not a string length issue because any length string as soon as I added .com on the end returns a 406 response.

There is a stacktrace in the logs, but I can't tell what the issue is by looking at it.

Can anyone advise what's wrong? and potentially how to fix it? Is it an escaping thing?

```
14:05:34.277 ERROR com.ideafactory.mvc.general.controllers.AjaxController 105 handleError - Request: http://localhost:8080/admin/customers/json/customer_suggest/Rich%40mailinator.com raised org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:121) ~[AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:89) ~[AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193) ~[RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [CharacterEncodingFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [ExceptionTranslationFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [SessionManagementFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [RequestCacheAwareFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [LogoutFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) [CsrfFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [HeaderWriterFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119) [MultipartFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
```

Answer (score 1):

When the path is ending with .something, string interprets it as a file extension, and as of 3.2 version it by default tries to find the proper representation based on the extension. I believe that this is your case, and it complains that it cannot find any mime type registered with *com* extension.

You have the solutions discussed here [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated), one way forward is to have your mapping accept dot so something like `/admin/customers/json/customer_suggests/{variable:.+}` or turn of file extension content negotiation, if you're using XML config something like

```
    <beans:bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
                class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
       <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" enable-matrix-variables="true" content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    ...
   </annotation-driven>
```