# What is String:.+ in spring request mapping's path param

Tags: spring, rest, spring-rest, request-mapping

While I was modifying the code written by other developer I come across an end point `@RequestMapping(value = "/ICD/{icdcode:.+}` and wanted to know what is :.+ in the path variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been answered

[Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated)

[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

[Spring - Path variable truncate after dot - annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419743/spring-path-variable-truncate-after-dot-annotation)

Basically, it is a regular expression. Spring considers that anything behind the last dot is an extension and get rid of it.

If you have a mapping to `/somepath/{email}` and try `/somepath/test@gmail.com` the value for the path parameter `email` will be `test@gmail`

Using the regular expression {pathparam:.+} everything is considered part of the value, even what is behind the last dot.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It would have been answered but when I search exactly with the key words I didn't find any matching answers.