# Rest Api in Spring with parameter as a email id giving HTTP status 406

Tags: spring, url-encoding, spring-rest, request-mapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/analyst/getcompany/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public String getEmail(@PathVariable String user) {
    //logic
    }
```

when requesting this URI with:

```
"analyst/getcompany/Abc@gmail.com"
```

It is giving HTTP Status 406.

I encode the @ with %40 but {.} in the email id is creating a problem. how to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: @Prashant can you share how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will help you.  [Path variable truncate after dot - annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33826204/5429215)

You have to add trailing slash at the end of the path variable after name like

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/analyst/getcompany/{user}/")
```

The Request like

http://localhost:8080/analyst/getcompany/Abc@gmail.com/

Comment: I found that it is advisable not to use trailing slash because it is not maintainable, if found that @ and .c,.co are accepted but .com is giving 406.
for eg. abc@gmail.co,abc@gmail.ss are accepted but abc@gmail.com is not working as the suffix .com is the real cause.