# How do I get all the filename with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, file, api, model-view-controller

I have a button which sends the filename to API, but API gets only name of file (not included extension). How do I get extension?

JS

```
<button class="upl-btn" data-url="validacao/upload/planilha/55163343b0df070bbc66e1bb6e0c3f9b.xlsx" data-type="DELETE">
<span>Apagar</span>
</button>
```

API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/validacao/upload/planilha")
@Api(hidden = true, value = "/planilha", description = "API para envio de planilhas para validação")
public class UploadPlanilhaAPI {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}",  method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public Response deleteFile(@PathVariable("name")String name){
            HttpSession session = activeUser.getSession();
            String path = (String) session.getAttribute("dir");
            uploadPlanilhaService.deletePlanilha(path, name);
            session.removeAttribute("json");
            session.removeAttribute("ignored");
            session.setAttribute("lastuploaddate", Util.now());
            return Response.ok().build();
        }
}
```

Result is `name = 55163343b0df070bbc66e1bb6e0c3f9b`, I wanna `name = 55163343b0df070bbc66e1bb6e0c3f9b.xlsx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering Spring's optional suffixes feature.  By default, Spring lets you declare a `/myPage` request mapping.  Now it lets you call `/myPage.jsp`, `/myPage.json` and Spring handles the translation of the response into the required type.  It's quite annoying that they've switched it on by default; especially if the final part of your URL is a path variable: it ends up trimming the final `.` part off because it thinks you're trying to use this feature.

If you aren't interested in this feature, you can turn it off.

In your servlet xml file, add this `path-matching` setting:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching registered-suffixes-only="true"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Alternative solutions here:
[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)