# Angularjs : How to pass "." character into a parameter for $resource

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, rest

I am calling a web api (J2ee, for example : **/getBlDetail/{noBl}**) with $resource:

```
return $resource('api/getBlDetail/:noBl', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET', isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
```

J2EE :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBlDetail/{noBl}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<Vente> getBlDetail(@PathVariable String noBl) {
    try {
        noBl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(noBl, "UTF-8");
        ...
        return ventes;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If for example noBl = '04.00256', in java side I am only getting '04'.
It seems that the "." character is not accepted.
I have tried : **encodeURIComponent(bl.noBl)**
But the problem is the same.

Is there a way to use a parameter in $resource that contains the "." character?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the URL differently, like so:

/somepath/{variable:.+}

Further explanation in this question:
[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)