# Mismatch in @PathVariable resolving

Tags: spring-mvc

Let's suppose to have this method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyusers/{site}/{users}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody   
public List<String> verifyUser(
    @PathVariable("site") String site, @PathVariable("users") String[] users) {
    ...
}
```

Receving a request like GET /verifyusers/AOUD/farmaci.rain,farmaci.postacuti

we get: site="AOUD" and users = [farmaci.rain, farmaci] that is we lose the second part of second String after dot ("postacuti")

I think it's the fault of org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to prevent truncation of parameter after ' . '

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyusers/{site}/{users:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody   
public List<String> verifyUser(
    @PathVariable("site") String site, @PathVariable("users") String[] users) {
    ...
}
```

Note: `{users:.+}`