# How to get parameter which is containing dot(.) from rest url in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application using Spring REST and hibernate. Here i am fetching record from database using unique username which is coming from url.
But the problem is that if i am writing simple string then it is working fine but when in username i am writing dot(.) then no result is coming from database.

For ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/WhoToSubscribe/subscribe/anshul007
```

but when i am using this url

```
http://localhost:8080/WhoToSubscribe/subscribe/nadeem.ahmad095
```

it is not working because it is containing dot(.)

Here is my **controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{uname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Profession> getSubscriber(@PathVariable("uname") String uname) {

    List<Profession> pro = null;

    try {
        pro = subscribeService.getProfessionById(uname);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pro;
}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Profession> getProfessionById(String uname) throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  String queryString = "from Profession where username = :uname";
  Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
  query.setString("uname", uname);
  //List<Profession> queryResult = (List<Profession>) query.uniqueResult();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return query.list();
}
```

Comment: which spring version are you on?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated

Comment: okay...but i was unable to understand that question

Comment: it is related to the same problem you are facing

Comment: okay... But i got the solution now in below answer :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

change your mapping to `/somepath/{variable:.+}`

or add a slash at the end `/somepath/{variable}/`

Comment: I tried but i had an exception "'The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: '.+'.'
"

Answer (score 2):

As alternativ to @Jkikes answer you can generally turn this behavior of with:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
  }

}
```

Now you can use dots everywhere :D