# Emails in restful spring Get request url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am having a problem with passing emails in http url using spring. My url looks as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/users/{email}
```

I am using spring mvc to handle this GET request.

Using my browser url bar or using Postman when I do the following

```
http://localhost:8080/users/sampleEmail@gmail.com
```

I only see sampleEmail@gmail in the spring controller code. For some reason the ".com" part is stripped out. Would anyone know if I am doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is because Spring truncates whatever is coming after DOT(.) assuming it to be an extension.

Refer this:
[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Is there a requirement that you need to use only GET? If not then switch to POST and send JSON Object with required parameters such as {email: "abc@xyz.com"}