# Handling Spring MVC Controller method with @PathVariable at root (like /{domain})

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to implement an application which queries data based on a **@PathVariable.** Slight complexity is that the path variable is at the root. 
I mean it's like **mydomain.com/{myVar}**.

When I try to implement something like this, the issue is it's clashing with many resources directly under the root (eg: index.html).

As a part of solving the problem,
I tried to serve static resources under root from controller individually(Though it doesn't sound like a proper solution), But, not sure how to send the resources using Spring Controller methods.

Also, I tried to see if there was a way to exclude url-mappings within **@RequestMapping**, But didn't work.

Is there a way to implement this? What would be the best and efficient practice?

My application currently uses Spring boot with gradle, and static resources are under **src/main/webapp**
Any help is appreciated, Thank you

Comment: `it's clashing with many resources directly under the root (eg: index.html).` Does that give you exception or what happens ? What if the path variable doesn't have any value ? Think thats the case it encounters

Comment: Yes, It makes application not load. Its because, resource request for **index.html** is also captured within the same request (**myVar value is 'index.html'**), and I am not sure how to handle that request properly.

Comment: The first conflict I faced is with **index.html**, I don't think I encountered a case where path variable doesn't have a value within that request (But, I believe that it was a separate request which triggered the **index.html** resource request).

Comment: This thread should help you : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: That thread is totally different, I don't have a problem of variable getting truncated. I am dealing with /{myVar} type path variable.