# Request Mapping with a dot (.) in last path

Tags: spring-mvc

I have following request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", produces = { MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Resource<UserDTO> findUser(@PathVariable final String userId) {
    User user = administrationService.getSecurityUserById(userId);
    return userResourceAssembler.toResource(modelMapper.map(user, UserDTO.class));
}
```

I use `RestTemplate` to get the resource. The user ids passed in the url contain a dot (.) like: **john.doe**  -> request URL: `http://mysite/users/john.doe`
When the above method gets called I only get **john** in @PathVariable userId.

How can this be fixed? to get **john.doe**

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything that goes after a dot in RequestMapping is considered an extension and therefore ignored, if you want to be able to read along with the dot and the rest of the string I recommend using a regex in your Request mapping such as: `/{userId:.+}` 
more detailed explanation can be found here: [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)