# Sending parameter inThymleaf using link urls @

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following form in my **Thymleaf** page:

```
  <div class="panel-body">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Issue Date</th>
                <th>Payment Schedule</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Send Invoice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-row" th:each="p : ${POList}">
                <td th:text="${p.issueDate}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.paymentSchedule}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.total}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.status}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.rentalPeriod.startDate}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.rentalPeriod.endDate}"></td>

                <td>
                <form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${po}" th:method="post" th:action="@{'/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice(email=${po.Email})'}">

                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Send Invoice</button>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

I have tried to send the value of `po.Email` to the method.
I thought the `th:action="@{'/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice(email=${po.Email})'}"`
will make a link like `dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice/{Email}`

So i tried to get it in the method like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=POST, path="makeAndSendInvoice")
    public String makeAndSendInvoice(@PathVariable("email") String email){

        System.out.println("Invoice is sent to..................."+email);
        return "Invoice";
    }
```

but it seems to me it does not work, since it does not recognize my method.
So how can recieve the `po.Email` in my method

Comment: @Ralph ...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `th:action` to:

```
th:action="@{/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice/{email}(email=${po.Email})}"
```

and add the `PathVariable` in the `RequestMapping` value like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, path="/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice/{email:.+}")
public String makeAndSendInvoice(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
```

From [Thymeleaf - Link URLs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls):

> Variable templates are also allowed in URL paths, like
>   `@{/order/{orderId}/details(orderId=${orderId})}`
>
> ```
> <!-- Will produce '/gtvg/order/details?orderId=3' (plus rewriting) -->
> <a href="details.html" th:href="@{/order/details(orderId=${o.id})}">view</a>
>
> <!-- Will produce '/gtvg/order/3/details' (plus rewriting) -->
> <a href="details.html" th:href="@{/order/{orderId}/details(orderId=${o.id})}">view</a>
> ```

From [Spring - URI Template Patterns](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates):

> In Spring MVC you can use the `@PathVariable` annotation on a method
>   argument to bind it to the value of a URI template variable:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
> public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
>   Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
>   model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
>   return "displayOwner";
> }
> ```

Comment: when i print the email value in the method it has a value like this **{email}(email=${p**

Comment: I've done a typo. The path in @{...} should be unquoted. Edited.

Comment: Thanks it is working, but when i sent sth like **salman@ut.ee**
it does not consider **.ee** part, it does not consider characters after the dot

Comment: That's a Spring MVC matter. Here you can find a detailed explanation: [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)