# Spring REST - How to enforce response type being JSON when URL ends with .xml

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-restcontroller

My Spring REST API has trouble (=> `406`) when an endpoint ends with a file name, e.g. `/file/example.xml` because it assumes the result should be XML but thats wrong (it should be JSON).

`Written [{timestamp=Thu Oct 20 11:11:14 CEST 2016, status=406, error=Not Acceptable, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException, message=Could not find acceptable representation, path=/file/foobar.xml}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7015ebef]`

I read something about a Spring 4 feature detecting the file extensions and overwritting the response type, so I tried to enforce the response type but I did not find a solution.

Here is my REST controller:

```
@CompileStatic
@RestController
class ImportFileController {
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/file/{fileName:.+}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            produces = "application/json"
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public ImportFile update(
            @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
            @RequestBody ImportFile importFile) {
        // ..
        return importFile
    }
}
```

This is the request/response:

```
Request PUT /file/foobar.xml {"reader_name":"something"}
Response 406 {
  "timestamp" : "2016-10-20 08:56:35",
  "status" : 406,
  "error" : "Not Acceptable",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
  "message" : "Could not find acceptable representation",
  "path" : "/file/foobar.xml"
}
```

What I tried:

- Using `{filenName:.+}` instead of `{fileName}`
- Using `produces` in my `@RequestMapping`
- Sending a custom `Accept` header (`application/json`)
- Setting `spring.mvc.path-matching.suffix-pattern` to `true` or `false` but that was just a wild guess

What worked:

- Changing endpoint from `/file/{fileName:.+}` to `/file/{fileName:.+}/update`
  But that's just a workaround, not a solution.

**Important**: I'm using Groovy and I'm using YML configuration.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743941/1496158. This post describes how to either disable the handler mapping or only enable the handler mapping for specific extensions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it's for Java/XML config only

Comment: But there surely must be a way to configure Spring beans? This was meant as a pointer to what to configure.

Comment: Ah yes I have a beans.xml, thought in wrong mindset. When adding the `handlerMapping` bean I can't compile anymore, `No bean named 'contentNegotiationManager' is defined`, when using the second code snippet I got `Method viewResolver in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter required a single bean, but 2 were found:` `contentNegotiationManager: defined in class path resource [beans.xml]` `mvcContentNegotiationManager: defined by method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' ...`

Comment: The problem is I'm also using the Rest stuff, not the Mvc stuff directly, so I can't set or overwrite any handlers, right? At least I can't build successfully with those solutions. I'll take the workaround, adding a slash to the endpoint's URL :(

Comment: Couldn't you for the first code snippet try to use mvcContentNegotiationManager: `<property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="mvcContentNegotiationManager"/>`?

Comment: Alternatively you should be able to override the mvcContentNegotiationManager in the configuration by setting the id to mvcContentNegotiationManager instead of contentNegotiationManager in the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define, that your method consumes json as well, using [@RequestMapping options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--):

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/file/{fileName:.+}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            produces = "application/json",
            consumes = "application/json",
    )
```

This should prevent your application from trying to convert the data into XML.

Also make sure that Client is setting the "Content-Type" header properly

Comment: Unfortunatelly it has no effect on the result, I still receive 406-Not acceptable