# Convert string with more than 20 digits to a number using Java

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I have this string:

```
0.023526112354180534
```

How can I transform this string to number, and maybe more digits? I tried Double.parseDouble and not work

**EDIT**

You are right.

I´m making a call from Javascript and my call is:

```
url : "/myapp/data/selectedCampaign/thermal/"+data
```

data=0.023526112354180534

When I entered this method in Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectedCampaign/{type}/{evidenceValue}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Double> getValues(@PathVariable("type") String type,
            @PathVariable("evidenceValue") String evidenceValue)
```

evidenceValue is 0 and I was parsing 0

I still don t know why.
**EDIT 2**

I reolve this issue by going to:

[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Did you tried BigDecimal??

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` seems to work perfectly. What issue exactly are you experiencing with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `new BigDecimal("0.023526112354180534");`

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("0.023526112354180534");
System.out.println(d);
```

worked without problems for me at least without precision loss

Edit: As far as I know the only difference between Double.parseDouble(String) and BigDecimal is the precision, so if precision is important, you should use BigDecimal

Comment: Won't work without precision loss for almost any number with more than 16 digits.

Comment: @FredK you are right ^^ I was just editing the comment