# Limitation of path in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, url, path

I came across an interesting question while working with Spring and REST API and that problem is: Is the path limited to a certain number of characters in Spring?

The code is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = {REST_PREFIX + "/{key}"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public DashboardItem getExceptionByKey(@PathVariable("key") String key, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse_p) {
    log.info("URL is {}", request.getRequestURL());
    log.info("Key is {}", key);
    return InspectionUtils.getExceptionByKey(key);
}
```

An example of a key is

```
67E4D2C089CBCCA2A9732F6986124C6B10.243.2.107#0EEE5EAB06ED4FFF82A8934F7058860C#79A2F0C170A028A3B0410F0F16303F41
```

When sending the request I made sure to encode the URL and in my program the URL I am receiving is the following

```
/rest/exceptions/67E4D2C089CBCCA2A9732F6986124C6B10.243.2.107#0EEE5EAB06ED4FFF82A8934F7058860C#79A2F0C170A028A3B0410F0F16303F41
```

Thus I am receiving the hole key, but when it parses it, the variable key is only

```
67E4D2C089CBCCA2A9732F6986124C6B10.243.2
```

I thought that it may be special characters, but it doesn't look like it. My second guess is that there is a limitation for the length of the path.

So my question to you is if there is a limitation regarding the path or is there another problem?

Thank you

Comment: To answer your last question: yes, there is a limitation to the URL length -- browsers limit this to about 2000 characters.  No, you are not hitting this limitation yet in Spring.

Comment: I know about the 2000 character limitation. I was referring to the path variable, if it has a limitation

Comment: It has no limitation.  Please show us where you are determining the key is cut off, I see no print statement, I only see another piece of code that may or may not be handling key incorrectly (`InspectionUtils.getExceptionByKey(key)`)

Comment: My bad. I was printing the key before that call. I have updated the code in the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some kind of spring convention that treats everything after the last dot as a file extension and cuts it off. You could simply try adding a trailing / in your request mapping and the request.
I.e. `REST_PREFIX + "/{key}/"`

For a more complicated but better solution if you are not the one calling your API see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I have been looking for. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It must be the hash `#` character in your `key` which is not getting URL encoded. And since anything that comes after `#` in the URL represents different fragments of the HTML page, it never gets sent to the server.

On using javascript's `encodeURIComponent()` on your `key` i got:

`67E4D2C089CBCCA2A9732F6986124C6B10.243.2.107%230EEE5EAB06ED4FFF82A8934F7058860C%2379A2F0C170A028A3B0410F0F16303F41`

Notice the `#` character is now encoded. Try this, but you might need to decode it on your server.

Comment: I have encoded the character in my Javascript code with encodedURIComponent() as that was my first problem. After that in my Java code the path I receive is correct, but the key is truncated. Also it gets automatically decoded on the server. My problem is that it is truncated not at the # but before

Comment: Eliminate in between sources of problems.  Try do the call from PostMan, look at the Webserver access log to see what URL was actually sent.  Make your endpoint `REST_PREFIX + "/**"` and look at what URL you're getting.

Comment: I have done that as I mentioned before and the URL that I am getting on the Web server when logging it is good, the key is complete. When it is parsed, the key stops before the third dot.

Comment: Then log the key you are getting, or change the endpoint to `/**` as I suggested.  Inject the HttpServletRequest and print the contents of getURI.

Comment: I have also logged the key, and as I said the key is truncated before the third dot. I do not want to change the endpoint to /** and this will bring issues with my other code. A workaround I have found would be to use query parameters, but I am curious as to this problem.

Comment: @Ancuta follow the link in Rob's answer. Doing `/{key:.+}` on request mapping can help.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading that now and it seems that is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: That's really archaic behaviour of Spring... luckily it can turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character has a special meaning in a URL.  It is a fragment identifier, and it is used to jump to a certain part of a page (instead of landing at the top).  To avoid this, encode the character as `%23`.

Comment: This is not the solution, as you can clearly see the path being cut off at the dot.

Comment: And as I said in my post, the character is being encoded when sent to the server.

Comment: See my comment about eliminating other sources of problems.  Spring is not the one cutting off your URL, as I know from experience it can handle URL's far far longer than this one.