# What does ":.+" in `{param:.+}` means (java)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What does the `:.+` at `{param:.+}` mean in this set of code in java? I have tried searching however i do not find any explanation. Someone who knows please do explain it to me. Thank you so much.

**BatchFileController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param:.+}")  
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) 
{  
RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();  
return rbf.runBatch(fileName);  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The colon `:` is separator between the variable name and a regular expression.

The expression `.+` means at least one of any character.

Comment: Hi, please can you add some trivial example of the meaning? :)

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, I would like to give somemore context so that you could help me to better understand this. The URL i have to call is `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/test123.bat`. If i just put `@RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param}` i am not able to run the test123.bat file. I have to type it as `@RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param:.+}` why is that so?

Comment: @SushaNaidu that is because of the `.` in the filename, i'm guessing the server assumes that you want to access a file. But with the regex the server knows that the `.` character is allowed too

Comment: Spring truncates the file extension in a normal path variable, and doesn't in a regular expression path variable. There's more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Answer (score 1):

This is used if in case your path variable has `.` in them. For example, if you want to pass a inner field in mongo as a path variable to fetch from database. (student.address.id). By default everathing after the first dot is ignored. To tell spring framework not to truncate `:.+` is used.