# Rest API URL not working in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

This is my get method in spring boot

```
@GetMapping(value="/generateotp/{username}")
    public String generateOTP(@PathVariable(value = "username") String userName) {
        loginService.generateOTP(userName);
        return "OTP Generated";
    }
```

From my rest client I'm hitting with Url

```
http://localhost:8080/generateotp/shaik.moulali
```

But It is taking only shaik, it is neglecting after '.' part. But when I'm giving Url like `http://localhost:8080/generateotp/shaikmoulali`. It is accepting. Can I know the reason.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `/` at the end of the url solved the issue.

```
http://localhost:8080/generateotp/shaik.moulali/
```

We can also solve this by giving that parameter in body as post request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use some special characters, you have to set up a regex for Spring. [See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Don't add links as answers. Put it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

`.` is not a valid in the way you are using. If a value is to be used in url they should be properly escaped. (shaik%2Emoulali)

[Char that needs to be escaped](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

So when you are making call to your controller try to send encoded url and that should work.