# Rest API resource contains dot and last part gets cut off

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, file-extension

I'm creating a Rest api in Java with Spring and have urls such as

`GET http://host:port/products/{resource}`

The id's of resources are typically like version numbers such as `3.2` or a more elaborate example is `x-light.5p`.

Unfortunately, Spring seems to cut off the last part, thinking it is an extension (like `.html` or `.png`) so what actually enters my controller is not `3.2` but `3` and not `x-light.5p` but `x-light`. I experimented a bit and noticed that ending the request with an additional slash does work: `GET http://host:port/products/x-light.5p/` does enter the controller in full.

For obvious reasons, changing our id's is a no go. Why is Spring behaving this way and can I change it? What would happen if I change my controller mapping from `/products/{resource}` to `/products/{resource}/`? Is this a way to enforce those who call the api to append the last slash? I thought the last slash was mostly redundant.

Comment: It's confusing to ask a question about URLs with "dots" and obfuscate the hostname with `...`, you might want to change that.

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated

Answer (score 1):

User path mapping like this

> {resource:.+}

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/products/{resource:.+}")
    public void myMthod(@PathVariable("id") String resource) {

    ....
    }
```

Comment: This works - will also accept multiple parameters sorted by /

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution metioned in @benji2505 post or the below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void products(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String pattern = (String)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);  
    String resource = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, request.getPathInfo());

}
```