# Spring-boot MVC file suffix regression?

Tags: spring-boot

Previous to Boot 2.0.0 we used:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{ipAddress:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

which allowed us to pass in an IP address and not have it drop the last octet thinking it was a file name suffix, this is documented on several posts.

In 2.0.0, this still works, except for addresses ending in .123. which cause a 406.

Have managed to workaround using tips from https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation and [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated) but might be a useful catch for someone else?

Regards