# Spring MVC resource mapping with dot in the URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to add support in our iOS app for [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). So, our server needs to serve up a json file at the path `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. I created the file with filename `apple-app-site-association` in the folder `src/main/resources/well-known/` and added the following to our application config:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler(".well-known/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/well-known/");
}
```

However, this results in a 404 from the server. After trying many different things, I found that if I took the dot out like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("well-known/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/well-known/");
}
```

and navigated to `/well-known/apple-app-site-association`, it worked just fine. However, it needs to have the `.` in the URL.

Is there some way I can make this work? We are using Spring 4.3.7 and Spring Boot 1.4.5.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this with a `ResourceHandler`, but this may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While digging into this more, I saw the in the Javadoc for `addResourceHandler` the following:

`Patterns like "/static/**" or "/css/{filename:\\w+\\.css}"} are allowed.`

So, I updated the mapping to look like the following:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("{filename:\\.well-known}/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/well-known/");
```

After this change, things worked as expected. I found that it doesn't matter what is put before the colon, so this is what I finally ended up with:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("{wellKnownFolder:\\.well-known}/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/well-known/");
```

Comment: How did you set the MIME type for the file?

Comment: I have the same question, any news to this?