# Spring Controller doesnt accept url which ends with .uri

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have defined the below controller

```
@Controller
```

public class HelloController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/{name:.*}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> getValue(@PathVariable String name) {
    String value = "Hello World";
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

when i ping the url from the browser ex:
http://localhost:8080/example/config/test.abc

The request works fine.

But when i ping with url
http://localhost:8080/example/config/test.uri

it just blows the page with the error:
`The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.`

I tried MessageConverters and configureContentNegotiation nothing seems to be working.
I am wondering if spring treats test.uri as an invalid patterns or reserved keywords.

Environments i tried.
Spring 4/Tomcat 7 & 8
Spring 5/ Tomcat 9

Answer (score 2):

try a different regex.

instead of

```
.*
```

which means: a various number of any characters except new line

try

```
[a-z]*\.[a-z]*
```

which means 
a various number of a-z + a dot + a various number of a-z

if this is what you want.

if you dont need any pattern then just use

```
{name}
```

Checkout

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/uri-pattern.html

and

https://regexr.com/

But I would consider if you could adjust your API like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/{name}/{type}", ...
```

I think it is not a good idea to expect dots in your URI.
Dots means that you are requesting a file.

Checkout:

[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Could you please add explanation why test.test, test.url is working but test.uri not working ? in the answer

Comment: I tried {name} and [a-z]*\.[a-z]* no much luck. i cannot go the pattern of @RequestMapping(value = "/config/{name}/{type}" as that was a very big change for us

Comment: Then maybe try 
/somepath/{variable:.+}
as described in my last link

Answer (score 0):

Spring considers that anything behind the last dot is a file extension

To overcome this

modify our @PathVariable definition by adding a regex mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/{name:.+}"
```

And a safe guess would be

`.abc` is no extension type and `.uri` is one extension so maybe that's why your first URL works,

Answer (score 0):

i finally could able to fix the problem using ContentNegotiationConfigurer and setting the content type for uri.

```
    @Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer contentNegotiationConfigurer) {
    contentNegotiationConfigurer.mediaType("uri", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
}
```