# HTTP Status 406 in rest api spring boot when getByEmail

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-406, getmethod, rest

I want to search by email but always get "error": "Not Acceptable",

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{name:.+}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String name)  {
        return userService.getUserByEmail(name);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;

    }
    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(String email){
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).get();
        return user;
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

even It can fetch from database but when want to return throw error[image: fetch from db]

but throw error
[image]

add header application/json header but don't work.

another thing that I can get byId and firstName ,this work correctly

Comment: Can you please share the request and response headers

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated

Answer (score 1):

Try adding, value in **pathVariable** in the controller:

The content in bracket is a regex so it should work.

```
@GetMapping("/statusByEmail/{email:.+}/")
public String statusByEmail(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email){
  //code
}
```

And from the postman/rest-client

```
Get http://mywebhook.com/statusByEmail/abc.test@gmail.com/
```

If this doesn't work try to give the email in URLEncoded format:
The problem might be due to the multiple `.` in the request
Eg: `alireza.ca%40gmail.com`

OR

You can set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to automatically do the encoding of the url

Hopefully, this should work.

Comment: thanks .just add slash (/) end of {email:.+}/  and my problem solved ,but i don't understand why must add slash end of it.