# Spring rest api - Get method problem with dots

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, get

I have problem when trying to create get method which allows dots as a parameter.

```
    @GetMapping(path = "test/{id:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getTest(@PathVariable String id) {       

        return id;
    }
```

So it works for example for path

*test/core.txt*

But it does not for

*test/core.something*

I got error like

```
{
  "timestamp": 1623837131322,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "message": "Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory",
  "path": "/api/v1/test/core.somethign"
}

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory ...
```

Also tried to extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport with

```
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
```

I am using spring boot version 1.5.22.RELEASE.
Do you have any idea what can be wrong, seems like my configuration is ignored somehow

```
package eu.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource(
        ignoreResourceNotFound = false,
        value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Unfortunatelly not fully, I can use mapping like  @GetMapping(path = "test/{id}/")
but otherwise it won't work. 
I would like to avoid adding trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Add below bean in your appconfig file.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

**Update :** This class is deprecated. Now you have to use below code. I tested it and i'm posting here.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> test/abc.tera : abc.tera

> test/core.something : core.something

Comment: I did it, it was executed but still I have same error
 "Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory",

Comment: **UPDATE:**
From my perspective it should work, but still I have same error

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stay with this version of spring.

Comment: ```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource(
        ignoreResourceNotFound = false,
        value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to see the imports. Please add the code in question.

Comment: why did you imported RequestMappingHandlerMapping?

Comment: I forgot to remove it