# Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory

Tags: java, spring, maven

basically I created web project in spring and when I run it on local tomcat server it works fine, but the moment I uploaded project on Ubuntu server , I started getting this ** java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory
**
Important note that this error keeps appearing not when I start the server , but specifically when the program reaches these two controller methods.

This is basically

Controller Methods:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/image.do", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@RequestParam("imageId") String imageId , CommunityInfographicVO vo) throws Exception {
        logger.info("썹네일 이미지 controller 접근");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(imageId);
        vo.setInfoNo(id);
        List<CommunityInfographicVO> result = communityInfographicService.imageSelect(vo);
        logger.info("result from the DB got");

        if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
            String path = result.get(0).getFilePath();
            String fileName = result.get(0).getAtchFileNm();
            String originalFileName = result.get(0).getOrignlFileNm();

            String filePath = path + File.separator + fileName+originalFileName;
            logger.info("filePathCreated");

            if (filePath != null && fileName != null ) {
                try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))) {
                  
           byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream); 
           logger.info("fileBytes Created");
        // Return the image bytes in the response body
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fileBytes);
    }    
}
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/pdfImage.do", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdfImag(@RequestParam("imageId") String imageId ,@RequestParam("page") String page , CommunityInfographicVO vo) throws Exception {
            int infoNo= Integer.parseInt(imageId);
            int pageNo = Integer.parseInt(page);
            vo.setInfoNo(infoNo);
            List<CommunityInfographicVO> result = communityInfographicService.fileSelect(vo);
            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                String path = result.get(0).getFilePath();
                String fileName = result.get(0).getAtchFileNm();
                String originalFileName = result.get(0).getOrignlFileNm();

                String filePath = path + File.separator + fileName+originalFileName;
                File file = new File(filePath);
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
                PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);            
                byte[] bytes = null;
                

                    BufferedImage imageObj = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNo, 100, ImageType.RGB);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(imageObj, "jpg", baos);
                    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(bytes);
                
        }
            return null;      
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you might be seeing this error is because by putting the `.do` you are basically putting a path extensions

I do not know what version of Spring you are using, but from their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match):

> Starting in 5.3, by default Spring MVC no longer performs .* suffix pattern matching where a controller mapped to /person is also implicitly mapped to /person.*. As a consequence path extensions are no longer used to interpret the requested content type for the response — for example, /person.pdf, /person.xml, and so on.
> Using file extensions in this way was necessary when browsers used to send Accept headers that were hard to interpret consistently. At present, that is no longer a necessity and using the Accept header should be the preferred choice.
> Over time, the use of file name extensions has proven problematic in a variety of ways. It can cause ambiguity when overlain with the use of URI variables, path parameters, and URI encoding. Reasoning about URL-based authorization and security (see next section for more details) also becomes more difficult.

> To completely disable the use of path extensions in versions prior to 5.3, set the following:

> useSuffixPatternMatching(false), see PathMatchConfigurer

> favorPathExtension(false), see ContentNegotiationConfigurer

> Having a way to request content types other than through the "Accept" header can still be useful, e.g. when typing a URL in a browser. A safe alternative to path extensions is to use the query parameter strategy. If you must use file extensions, consider restricting them to a list of explicitly registered extensions through the mediaTypes property of ContentNegotiationConfigurer.

So given, this consider using the recommendations from the documentation.
I also believe your question is similar to [Spring rest api - Get method problem with dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000437/spring-rest-api-get-method-problem-with-dots)

Comment: Thank You for your answer, But the problem was in difference of Environment on the server and on my local machine. The solution was found randomly just by removing ResponseEntity<byte[]> as a response type and using ModelView instead