# Pact: no HttpMessageConverter found for response type

Tags: java, spring-boot, pact

So I have two Spring boot projects. In project A I call out to project B's controller via a service class to retrieve a ResponseEntity containing a list of strings. Project A's service class being the consumer and B being the provider in Pact terminology:

**BookServiceInterfaceImpl.java**

```
@Service("bookService")
public class BookServiceInterfaceImpl implements BookServiceInterface {

public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getBookTitlesForCourse(final String courseId){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8888/api/book/course/" + courseId, String[].class);
    List<String> titles = Arrays.asList(response.getBody());
    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(titles, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

**BookController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BookController {

private BookService bookService;

@Autowired
public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/book/course/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String[]>getBookTitlesForCourse(@PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    List<Book> books = bookService.findAllBooks();
    if(books.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    String[] bookTitles = books.stream()
            .filter(book -> book.getCourseId() == id)
            .map(book -> book.getTitle())
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    return new ResponseEntity<String[]>(bookTitles, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

I'm trying to use Pact to create a contract between the two. Thus far I have the following test in the consumer:

**BookServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BookServiceTest {

@Rule
public PactProviderRuleMk2 mockProvider = new PactProviderRuleMk2("test_provider", "localhost", 8080, this);

@Pact(provider="test_provider", consumer="test_consumer")
public RequestResponsePact createPact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    return builder
            .given("test state")
            .uponReceiving("BookServiceTest test interaction")
                .path("/api/book/course/1")
                .method("GET")
            .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .body("{[\"Dont make me think\",\"Clean Code\"]}")
            .toPact();
}

@Test
@PactVerification("test_provider")
public void test_retrieveBooksForcourse_validCourseId_success() {
    //given
    final String courseId = "1";
    BookServiceInterfaceImpl bookService = new BookServiceInterfaceImpl();
    //when
    ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = bookService.getBookTitlesForCourse(courseId);
    //then:
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(200));
    assertThat(response.getBody().size(), is(2));
}
}
```

And the pom file for the consumer is:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ocr</groupId>
<artifactId>new-consumer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>new-consumer</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Pact Test function failed with an exception: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Ljava.lang.String;] and content type [application/octet-stream]
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.validateResult(BaseProviderRule.java:164)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule$1.evaluate(BaseProviderRule.java:77)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Ljava.lang.String;] and content type [application/octet-stream]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:312)
at com.ocr.newconsumer.service.BookServiceInterfaceImpl.getBookTitlesForCourse(BookServiceInterfaceImpl.java:29)
at com.ocr.newconsumer.controller.BookServiceTest.test_retrieveBooksForcourse_validCourseId_success(BookServiceTest.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.lambda$runPactTest$1(BaseProviderRule.java:150)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseMockServer.runAndWritePact(MockHttpServer.kt:152)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.ConsumerPactRunnerKt.runConsumerTest(ConsumerPactRunner.kt:13)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.runPactTest(BaseProviderRule.java:148)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.access$100(BaseProviderRule.java:21)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule$1.evaluate(BaseProviderRule.java:76)
... 20 more
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.lambda$runPactTest$1(BaseProviderRule.java:150)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseMockServer.runAndWritePact(MockHttpServer.kt:152)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.ConsumerPactRunnerKt.runConsumerTest(ConsumerPactRunner.kt:13)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.runPactTest(BaseProviderRule.java:148)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule.access$100(BaseProviderRule.java:21)
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.BaseProviderRule$1.evaluate(BaseProviderRule.java:76)
... 20 more
```

So I'm not what exactly the issue is, from what I know I'm pretty sure this kind of conversion shouldn't be a big thing and should be handled by Spring. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly with regards to the REST call or the test(first time using Pact)? Am I missing a dependency in the pom that I've assumed the Spring Boot parent/dependencies would have?

Answer (score 0):

For our consumer tests we extend `ConsumerPactTestMk2`.  One of the methods that you have to override is `runTest(MockServer ms)`.  The `MockServer` in the `runTest` method has the host portion of the URL that you need to use.  So you need to change the URL in the imple class to use the augmented URL.

```
public class BookServiceInterfaceImpl implements BookServiceInterface {
    private String hostUrl = "http://localhost:8888";
    //provider setter for this variable.
```

With that in place then you can use the `hostUrl` to create your final URL.

```
ResponseEntity<String[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(hostUrl + "/api/book/course/" + courseId, String[].class);
```

Then in the `runTest` method.

```
@Override
protected void runTest(MockServer ms) throws IOException {
    BookServiceInterfaceImpl bookService = new BookServiceInterfaceImpl();
    bookService.setHostUrl(ms.getUrl());
```

EDIT:  [Here is an exmaple](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/examples/ExampleJavaConsumerPactTest.java).

Comment: so i think you're saying I should alter my implementation code to suit a test library, when shouldn't the test library do the work here regardless?I will try this approach regardless, just curious as i can't see anything around overriding runTest in the example on github im using as reference : https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/examples/ArticlesTest.java

Comment: Ok, I've implemented the change and altered the test to resemble the example posted. I still get the same HttpMessageConverter error so don't think that's the issue

Comment: Ah good point.  I have seen that error before and always found a way around it.  Have you seen this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857557/1490322