# Consume ArcGIS Feature Query Service in Java

Tags: java, rest, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-online

I am querying a feature layer provided in ArcGIS Online as explained in the [Query (Feature Service)](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-.htm) documentation. Everywhere there are examples using **JavaScript**. I am not able to find any documentation or examples using **Java**.

I have tried the same thing using [Spring's RestTemplate class](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) as below

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> variables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
 variables.add("where", "1 = 1");
 variables.add("f", "json");
 variables.add("outFields", "*");

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(variables, headers);

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

 String queryData = restTemplate.postForObject(this.SERVICE_FEATURE_URL + "/query", entity, String.class);
```

Here instead of getting the result as a **String** object, is it possible to get the data as an **ArcGIS Java** class object?

P.S. I know how to get the `arcgis-java` dependency using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
    <artifactId>arcgis-java</artifactId>
    <version>100.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this, but here are three things I do know. 1) You'll probably have to write your own `HttpMessageConverter` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857557/720773 ). 2) Even if you do, ArcGIS Runtime (the `arcgis-java` library) can't be used in a server process (see the FAQ in https://developers.arcgis.com/arcgis-runtime/licensing/ ), so if you're building a web app, it's probably not worth the trouble to write a custom converter that you can't use. 3) Because of #1 and #2, I think you're better off using a Java JSON library to parse the response into a JSON object.