# Rest template to send a message to Kafka using Schema Registary and Kafka Restproxy

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, resttemplate, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-rest

I am trying to create a simple Resttemplate which will fetch the schema from Schema Registary and if response is 200 it will fetch the Schema ID and send it along with message in Avro format to kafka. Here is my code:
.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
        public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

  String kafkarwsrproxyURL = String.format("%s/topics/%s", "https://kafka-rest-proxy-**********", "test-topic");
    String schemaurl = String.format("%s/subjects/%s/versions/latest", "https://schema-registry-*********", "test-topic");
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    
    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
     JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject eventenvolpe = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject jsondata  = new JSONObject();
     JSONArray jsonarray =new JSONArray();
     JSONObject recordvalue =new JSONObject();
  // connecting to schema registary and getting back schema   
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"));
    headers.setBasicAuth("username", "password");
    HttpEntity<String> SchemaEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
     
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(schemaurl, HttpMethod.GET, SchemaEntity, String.class);
         if(result.getStatusCodeValue()==200) {
             
             JsonNode rootNode = obj.readTree(result.getBody());
             JsonNode schema_id = rootNode.path("id");//fetchinf schema id form schema
             
             event = new JSONObject();
             record = new JSONObject();
             eventenvolpe = new JSONObject();
             jsondata  = new JSONObject();
            
            
            
            jsondata.put("data", obj.writeValueAsString(new Data("test1",1)));
            eventenvolpe.put("event_envelope", jsondata);
            recordvalue.put("value", eventenvolpe);
            jsonarray.put(recordvalue);
            event.put("value_schema_id", schema_id);
            event.put("records", recordvalue);//setting up event object to send to kafka
        
            System.out.println(event);
        
        //Sending message to kafka
        HttpHeaders messageheaders = new HttpHeaders();
        messageheaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json"));
        messageheaders.setBasicAuth("username", "password");
        HttpEntity<JSONObject> message = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(event,messageheaders );
         
        ResponseEntity<String> result1 = restTemplate.exchange(kafkarwsrproxyURL, HttpMethod.POST, message, String.class);
        
        if(result1.getStatusCodeValue()==200) {
            System.out.println("Message is pushed to Kafka");
        }
        
             
        
             
         }
         
    
}

 }
```

I am successfully able to fetch schema form registry but while sending back to kafka getting error.

```
2020-06-30 20:02:56.078  INFO 7972 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-30 20:02:59.235  INFO 7972 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : 
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8089 (http)
2020-06-30 20:02:59.263  INFO 7972 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : 
Starting service [Tomcat]
  2020-06-30 20:02:59.264  INFO 7972 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : 
 Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
 2020-06-30 20:02:59.434  INFO 7972 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : 
 Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 2020-06-30 20:02:59.434  INFO 7972 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3269 ms
2020-06-30 20:02:59.847  INFO 7972 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : 
Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-30 20:03:00.238  INFO 7972 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : 
Tomcat started on port(s): 8089 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-30 20:03:00.251  INFO 7972 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 
 Started DemoApplication in 4.945 seconds (JVM running for 5.758)
 {"records":{"value":{"event_envelope":{"data":" 
 {\"test\":\"test1\",\"testEventId\":1}"}}},"value_schema_id":"5"}
 2020-06-30 20:03:02.276  INFO 7972 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 
 'debug' enabled.
 2020-06-30 20:03:02.282 ERROR 7972 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
 Application run failed

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) [spring-boot- 
 2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot- 
2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]


at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot- 
 2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot- 
2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot- 
2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:44) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for 
org.json.JSONObject and content type "application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json"
at `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:961) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE] at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:91) [classes/:na] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE] ... 5 common frames omitted

2020-06-30 20:03:02.878 INFO 7972 --- [ main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down 
ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the trouble is cause by the fact that your client doesn't know how to read this "exotic" data type: "application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json"

Here's a possible solution in this post:
[no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854369/no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response-type)

To sum up - you either have to register the corresponding HttpMessageConverter for the MIME type "application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" or change (if you have access) the returning MIME type from server. You can also "hack" a quick proxy script, so that it goes to server and fetches data and then sends it to you client with changed MIME type.

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the code snippet:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
   final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   List<MediaType> types = Arrays.asList(
         new MediaType("application", "*+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET)
    );
   
   converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(types);
   messageConverters.add(converter);
   restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

   return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example of what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: Added a snippet of code to change RestTemplate to add the httpmessageconverter to handle that specific json. You might want to import a few dependencies to support MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter if that is already not there