# Unable to fetch response in text/html

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have a rest endpoint that returns content type `text/html`.

How can I read it, in a Spring boot app and keep it as `text/html` and return it?

I don't want to retrieve it as a String. I want it to remain as `text/html`.

This works but as said I want to preserve the text/html.

This ends up turning it into a large string in the response.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restOperations.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

If I try to just use Object:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restOperations.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class);
```

I end up with error:

> Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
> response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html]
> org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not
> extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response
> type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html]    at
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)

How could I resolve this?

Full code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestOperations restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(4000))
           .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(4000))
           .build();
    }

}

@RestController
public class MyController {
    private final String domain;
    private final RestOperations restOperations;

    public MyController(
        @Value("${domain}") String domain,
        RestOperations restOperations
    ) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Object get(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("name", name);
        }};

        String url = getEndPoint(domain, params);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);

        HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restOperations.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class);

        // some other logic

        return response.getBody();
    }

    private String getEndPoint(String endPoint, Map<String, String> params) {
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(endPoint);
        return builder.buildAndExpand(params).toUriString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854369/no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response-type

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this !! 
Return data/file as `Resource` from your controller.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restOperations.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, byte[].class);
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(response.getBody());
```

Return ResponseEntity from controller as

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .body(resource); // using ByteArrayResource
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serve text/html files like this:

```
@GetMapping(produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> serve() throws IOException{
   File file=new File("path to your file");
   InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   
   return ResponseEntity.ok(return is.readAllBytes());
}
```

And get text/html files like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> get(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
   File destination=new File("your destionation")
   OutputStream os=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destionation));
   os.write(file.getBytes());

   return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Hi the response I am retrieving is a res call in format text/html and I am returning the same as text/html. Is not file related.