# Spring mvc throwing org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using springMVC and I am getting following exception when trying to do an update.

```
10:10:49,847 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:250 - Released JDBC connection
10:10:49,859 DEBUG FixedContentNegotiationStrategy:48 - Requested media types is text/html (based on     default MediaType)
10:10:49,929 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public   com.model.JobQueue com.controller.TestResultController.updateJob(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
10:10:49,937 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public com.model.JobQueue com.controller.TestResultController.updateJob(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
10:10:49,938 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public com.model.JobQueue com.controller.TestResultController.updateJob(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
10:10:49,940 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
10:10:49,940 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
10:10:49,941 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
```

following is the controller method that throws the exception. Is there something that I need to do to make this work?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateJob", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody JobQueue updateJob(@RequestParam(value="job_id") String job_id, @RequestParam String test_id, @RequestParam(value="status") String status) {
   JobQueue job = jobqueueService.getJob(Integer.parseInt(job_id));
   job.setTest_id(test_id);
   job.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(status));
   jobqueueService.updateJob(job);
   return job;
}
```

I found following post [Spring MVC - HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception) where similar problem was discussed but I am not sure how to go about solving this with annotation.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

The exception was  thrown because of the return value of the controller.
Once I changed the return value the exception went away.

```
public @ResponseBody String updateJob(@RequestParam(value="job_id") String job_id){
```

I also changed the response to be null.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateJob", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String updateJob(@RequestParam(value="job_id") String job_id){
    Integer jobid = Integer.parseInt(job_id);

    JobQueue job = jobqueueService.getJob(jobid);
    .
    .
    return null;
}
```

Comment: However small it is. Never the less it is a valuable question with valuable answer. I have it correct at some place and I just forgot about it. This helped me to find my mistake quickly. So do not ignore this question. Thanks!!

Comment: @user1647708: So what if my return type is List<String>? what should I return?

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

Answer (score 1):

u can try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "audit/unaudit", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
```