# Swagger 2.0.3 with Spring MVC throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

I am using the following Maven dependencies and plugins

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>

  <repository>
        <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
        <name>jcenter</name>
        <!-- <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url> -->
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
  </repository>
```

in beans.xml below is the bean definition is as follows:

```
 <int:annotation-config/>
        <context:annotation-config/> 
        <bean id="swagger2Config" class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration"/>
<bean id="springConfig" class="com.example.SpringConfig"/>
```

I have referred to the following [blog](http://blog.trifork.com/2015/05/08/documenting-your-rest-apis/)

I can not use the early access version mentioned in the blog as it is not available for download.  I have changed the version to 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT and now I am seeing HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException exception. I was able to generate the WAR file and in logs I was able to see the resourcegroup that was created properly with Swagger when I tried to access it using  http://localhost:8080/example/v2/api-docs the above mentioned exception was thrown.

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation available here -> http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/ also I don't think you need to have 2 `annotation-config`s

Comment: yes , i have followed documentation too , bur still i m not able to resolve the exception

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like the dependencies are available on Maven Central again. That's an improvement since I wrote that blog. 
At least 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 are available there so no need to use JCentral any more if you don't want to.

As to the HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException. I didn't see that during my experimentation that led to writing that blog so I can't give you a definitive anwer.

While reading your question I did notice a few related questions here on SO:

[Spring MVC with Jackson 2.2: "HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101292/spring-mvc-with-jackson-2-2-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could-not-fin?rq=1)

[Spring mvc throwing org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384722/spring-mvc-throwing-org-springframework-web-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception?rq=1)

Those suggest there may be some general Spring MVC configuration related to Jackson 2 that is missing or the translation of the @ResponseBody could use some tweaking for a particular method. Check those questions to see which is more applicable to your situation.