# Errors using Spring 4.1 @RestController

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to return JSON when using the @RestController. I'm using Spring 4.1. 
Here's the exception I'm getting when calling listrestsites.html using a GET request.
I have the fasterxml Jackson core and databind jars in my build path.
Output of the accept from @requestheader = accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Any help is appreciated. Thank you,

> [DEBUG,ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from
>   handler [public java.util.List
>   com.amci.spring3.controller.SitesRestController.listRestSites(java.lang.String)]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation [DEBUG,DefaultListableBeanFactory]
>   Returning cached instance of singleton bean
>   'exceptionControllerAdvice' [DEBUG,ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver]
>   Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Here's my Restcontroller class:

```
@RestController
public class SitesRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AssetService assetService;


    @RequestMapping("/listrestsites.html") 
    public  List<Asset> listRestSites(@RequestHeader(value="accept") String accept) {

        System.out.println(getLogLevel());
        System.out.println("accept: " + accept);
        return assetService.findAssets();
    }

}
```

Also, snippet from my spring.xml:

```
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
      </bean>

     </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have the following in your Spring xml file:

```
<context:annotation-config/> 

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

and all items of your POJO should have getters/setters. Hope it helps

Credit [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I added in above couple weeks ago, and fixed the issue.

Comment: @MariaSpeicher whenever you find answers to your own question, please update it on StackOverflow it will help future users