# Serving static images in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying very simple scenario:

I generated a Spring Boot (v1.3.3) project using start.spring.io initialiser having selected Web dependency. I have then put sample JS, CSS and PNG files into `resources/static` folder and started up the webapp.

Now when I try to access JS and CSS resources everything's fine, but for the image it throws `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` (Could not find acceptable representation) and returns error 406.

Is there any configuration to be done to serve static images from resources/static folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems with returning JSON. It's only when I try to get image resources (png, jpg)

Answer (score 1):

No further configuration should be required. (I'm also serving images from the *static* folder of a Spring Boot v1.3.3 app.)

How are you accessing the images? Are you calling **servletContext.getResourceAsStream("filename")** from a Controller and returning a byte array? If that's the case you may need to add e.g. **produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE** to your **@RequestMapping** annotation.

If using JSPs you should just be able to use the Spring url tag in the following manner:

```
<spring:url value="/path/to/your-image.jpg" var="logoImg"/>
<img src="${logoImg}">
```

..where the path starts from within the *static* folder.