# Spring ResponseEntity<JSONObject> HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: json, spring

I try to return a JSONObject when a GET request is sent.

The method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{businessId}/{orderId}/{reportId}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getReport(@PathVariable("businessId") String businessId,
                                               @PathVariable("orderId") String orderId,
                                               @PathVariable("reportId") Long reportId) throws JSONException {
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(reportService.getReportJSON(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I get json from a file. The is a single json object there. In one line. I parse it to JSONObject like this

```
  fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));
  line = reader.readLine();
  while (line != null) {
    jsonObjectList = new JSONObject(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
  }
  return jsonObjectList;
```

This is what my file looks like.

```
{"reportId":"1","description":"СегментацияпоПоливозраст","orderId":"357","businessId":"НашКлиент№1","tables":[{"name":"Мужчины","fields":[{"name":"0-17","type":"number"},{"name":"18-24","type":"number"},{"name":"25-34","type":"number"},{"name":"35-44","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"}],"data":[2571,5287,4587,7705,3675,3743,7423]},{"name":"Женщины","fields":[{"name":"0-17","type":"number"},{"name":"18-24","type":"number"},{"name":"25-34","type":"number"},{"name":"35-44","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"}],"data":[7552,3107,6477,4967,9106,7859,9060]},{"name":"Мужчиныиженщины","fields":[{"name":"0-17","type":"number"},{"name":"18-24","type":"number"},{"name":"25-34","type":"number"},{"name":"35-44","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"},{"name":"45-54","type":"number"}],"data":[7552,3107,6477,4967,9106,7859,9060]}]}
```

I use postman to check my methods. This is the error I get

```
{
    "timestamp": 1504020107350,
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
    "message": "Not Acceptable",
    "path": "/audpro/report/1/1/1"
}
```

I tried to create a jsonobject by hand and pass it, but got the same error

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
response.put("id", 555);
response.put("message", "Provision successful!");
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

This is the library I use.

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
```

Why can't I return a jsonobject?

Comment: Hi @Evgenii I think this is a similar problem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I don't actually **need** JSONObject to get a json. I can return a String and it will be parsed as json. In the controller

```
  public ResponseEntity<String> getReport(@PathVariables) throws JSONException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(reportService.getReportJSON(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

And in the service I do

```
String json = line;
return json;
```

I'm still not sure about why returning a JSONObject is a no go though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning direct `JSONObject` in RestController class, you can set the objects in one POJO class and return in RestController class. 
`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in the annotation level will take care of conversion.In Future if you want to send both `xml` and `json`, simply you can extend more `MediaTypes` in annotation level, so that it can support `Multi MediaTypes`. Just follow [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) example.

Also make sure your including below dependency for `HttpMessageConversions`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better use `toMap()` function and then return it.

**Sample code**

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(jsonObject.toMap());
```