# spring - returning files in a response object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, file-io

I'm trying to return an image as a response in spring framework,
it works just fine implementing like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{photo}.{suf}")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable("photo") String photo,@PathVariable("suf") String suf) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/" + photo + "." +suf));
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

but when I try to return the image file inside a response object ,I get an org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException exception:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{photo}.{suf}")
public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getImage(@PathVariable("photo") String photo,@PathVariable("suf") String suf) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/" + photo + "." +suf));
    return new ResponseObject(IOUtils.toByteArray(in),1);
}
```

here is my ResponseObject implementation:

```
public class ResponseObject {
private Object object;
private int status;
public ResponseObject(Object object,int status){
    this.object = object;
    this.status = status;
}
public Object getObject() {
    return this.object;
}

public void setObject(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have jackson as your dependency?

Comment: have you tried having `ResponseObject.object` as `byte[]` instead of Object, are you trying to receive `byte[]` as a string?

Comment: @MichałBil no, can it be done without Jackson?

Comment: @Zeronex I can't convert ResponseObject.object to byte[] because I'm using it in other places in my project

Comment: @KiaMhn what is the **accept header** sent from your client side? This exception is thrown when spring cannot generate a response that is acceptable by the client.

Comment: @Sattyaki application/json

Comment: @KiaMhn have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception

Comment: @KiaMhn you must have jackson library in your classpath. Jackson is required for conversion to json format (as your client side accepts json).